# Laurent series about $\frac1{1-z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

to expand $\frac1{(1-z)^2}$, I seen book always differentiate $\frac1{1-z}$ to get the Laurent series, but why can't we multiply two expand of $\frac1{1-z}$ to get the series?
Like $\frac1{1-z}$ =  $\sum_{i=0}^n z^n $
therefore we get  $ (\sum_{i=0}^n z^n)^2 $

Comment: You can do that. Power series are very robust in the sense that you can add, subtract, multiply and divide them (by being careful when dividing). You can differentiate and anti-differentiate them and the result will still be uniform convergent.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that.

$$
\frac{1}{(1-z)^2} = \left(1+z+z^2+\dots\right) \left(1+z+z^2+\dots\right)\\
=1+(z\cdot 1+1\cdot z)+(1\cdot z^2+z^2\cdot 1+z\cdot z)+\cdots\\
=1+2z+3z^2+\cdots
$$

---

You could also use the Cauchy product formula, which states that:

$$\left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty b_j\right) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k$$ 
$$c_k=\sum_{l=0}^k a_l b_{k-l}$$

In your case $a_l=b_l = z^l$ so
$$c_k=\sum_{l=0}^k z^l z^{k-l} = (k+1)z^k$$

Comment: It should be noted that differentiation is computationally much more efficient than the Cauchy product, which is why we generally prefer differentiation.